# How to have many column from just one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table :

IADATA

```
    Id     Studentid     Mon   Value  Type
    1      ABC1           1      12     1
    1      ABC1           1      02     2
    1      ABC1           1      18     4
    1      ABC1           1      09     7
    1      ABC1           1      12     8
    1      ABC1           1      22     10
    1      ABC2           2      12     1
    1      ABC2           2      02     2
    1      ABC2           2      18     4
    1      ABC2           2      09     7
    1      ABC2           2      12     10
    1      ABC2           3      05     1
    1      ABC2           3      02     2
    1      ABC2           3      20     4
    1      ABC2           3      09     7
    1      ABC2           3      12     10
```

In the above table we have two Students ABC1 and ABC2 and their data.

Now the kind of result I want is as follows:

```
   Id      Studentid      Mon     Obtained   Benefits   Max    Type
    1        ABC1          1         12         02      18       I
    2        ABC1          1         09         12      22       II
    3        ABC2          2         12         02      18       I
    4        ABC2          2         09         00      12       II
    5        ABC2          3         05         02      20       I
    6        ABC2          3         09         00      12       II
```

Now in the result you can see that I am placing the values according to the studentid and mon and the types in a certain order. if the type is I it should have obtained, then benefits then max and same with II. What can be the select query for it?

The type in previous tables are linked. When it has the value 1,2,4 it should be like obtained, benefits and maximum for new type I and when 7,8,10, it should be like obtained,benefits and maximum for new type II. And when there is no column available, it should be zero.

Comment: Make your table complies with [second normal form (2NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

Comment: You should google - pivot tables in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT  ID,
        StudentID,
        Mon,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type LIKE 'Obtained%' THEN Value END) AS Obtained,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type LIKE 'Benefit%' THEN Value END) AS Benefit,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type LIKE 'Max%' THEN Value END) AS `Max`,
        CASE WHEN RIGHT(Type, 2) = 'II' THEN 'II' ELSE 'I' END AS Type
FROM    T
GROUP BY ID, StudentID, Mon, CASE WHEN RIGHT(Type, 2) = 'II' THEN 'II' ELSE 'I' END
ORDER BY ID, StudentID, Mon, Type
```

**[EXAMPLE ON SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01568/1)**

Although it would make more sense to store type separately. i.e. have one column for "obtained", "max" etc and another column for "I", "II"

**EDIT**

With your revised data structure this should work:

```
SELECT  ID,
        StudentID,
        Mon,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Type IN (1, 7) THEN Value END), 0) AS Obtained,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Type IN (2, 8) THEN Value END), 0) AS Benefit,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Type IN (4, 10) THEN Value END), 0) AS `Max`,
        CASE WHEN Type IN (7, 8, 10) THEN 'II' WHEN Type IN (1, 2, 4) THEN 'I' END AS Type
FROM    T
WHERE   Type IN (1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10)
GROUP BY ID, StudentID, Mon, CASE WHEN Type IN (7, 8, 10) THEN 'II' WHEN Type IN (1, 2, 4) THEN 'I' END
ORDER BY ID, StudentID, Mon, Type
```

**[EXAMPLE ON SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20e6b/3)**

Comment: Sorry there are few changes in the question.